# Scale single symbol in math mode

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols, scaling

I am using the Baskervald font with KP fonts for the maths font. It is very nice, but it needs some manual fine-tuning.

For example, the `\star` command gives an (oversized) **italic** star, which should not happen. I figured I just redefine `\star` as

```
\renewcommand{\star}{\scalebox{.5}{\bigstar}}
```

but this doesn't seem to work (`\star` is used in display mode).

What is the correct command to resize a particular command in math mode?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{kpfonts,baskervald}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  f\star g=fg+\hbar\{f,g\}\\
  f\bigstar g=fg+\hbar\{f,g\}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

`\star` is slanted, but `\bigstar` is not.

Comment: It would help for you to provide a complete minimum working example (MWE), beginning with `\documentclass`.  For example, I do not get a big italic star with `\star` and `\usepackage{baskervald}`.  So perhaps it is other packages you have loaded that are interacting with your font.  It is why a complete MWE is usually needed.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, I use `\scalerel` to replace the definition of `\star` with a `\bigstar` that is scaled to the same vertical footprint as the italic `\star`.  I tried putting a `\mathrel` around it, but the spacing to the `f` seemed odd, so I took it out.

The nice thing about this `scalerel` approach is that it will work in smaller math styles, as well, as shown below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{kpfonts,baskervald}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\let\savestar\star
\renewcommand\star{{\scalerel*{\bigstar}{\savestar}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  f\star g=fg+\hbar\{f,g\}\\
 \scriptstyle f\star g=fg+\hbar\{f,g\}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

as I said in my initial comment, loading just `baskervald` does not give an italic star.
Rather, the problem originates in the `kpfonts` package.  I get the same erroneous behavior loading just the `kpfonts` package.  Alternately, if I try to load `baskervald` first, I get an option clash, which I presume is `kpfonts` complaining that `baskervald` already took control of `\star` and it wants it too.

Comment: This works perfectly (I used `+` to give a more reasonable size for the star). Thank you very much.